# C# UWP Undo button

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, undo

Ok so i created an app to manage Score's for 2 teams. [APP Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYWDc.png). As you can see i have Team A and Team B, the 0 below adds the points for overall score, while below that you have a history of what points where earned each round.
when you press the go button the points from the 2 Textboxes go do the addition for all the score and add the points of that round in the lists.
As you can see i created an Undo button. so if for example i press the Go button by accident i can just tap on my undo button to undo button to undo my mistake. the thing is i don't know what code to write in the click event of undo button.

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Note: my lists are binded to a class i made. so each list displays the the property it needs through observablecollection.

```
class List
{
    public int ListA { get; set; }
    public int ListB { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lastState = Lists.Last();
        int teamAScore, teamBScore, listA, listB;

        // this way i got the Active scores.
        int.TryParse(CurrentScoreA.Text, out teamAScore);
        int.TryParse(CurrentScoreB.Text, out teamBScore);

        // this way i got the last score that i want to remove.
        listA = lastState.ListA;
        listB = lastState.ListB;

        // here i remove the last score from the Active one.
        teamAScore = teamAScore - listA;
        teamBScore = teamBScore - listB;

        // And here i replace my Active score with 
        // the new one that has the last states removed.
        CurrentScoreA.Text = teamAScore.ToString();
        CurrentScoreB.Text = teamBScore.ToString();

        // this one removes the last states of the list
        // so this way i can always remove the last part of my lsit
        // from both my active score and list till i go back to 0.
        Lists.Remove(lastState);
    }
```

Thnx a lot to the 2 guys that answered my questions below and by reading them and trying to execute them i found my solution!!!! :)

Comment: In theory, you would simply need to add a line to your click handlers that logs what action was performed (or even a running queue of actions performed). When undo is clicked, you'd simply reverse whatever the stored action was.

Comment: Undo should then return all items to a previous state... That could be done in two ways (maybe more):
1. Keep a previous state of the lists, copy the lists to a temporal list and save them to it, before doing any changes... but this may get heavy on resources use.
2. Keep a las mod variable, that allow you to apply the opposite action on the list, something like a struc change that include all possible changes, and store the last one done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pano, 
you can create a `List<List<List>>`(sry your class names doesn't help) that each time the user adds a score you will hold the values in a list like a state. So when you click undo you pop the Last Item from the List of List and replace to your list. Here is an example

```
List<List<Score>> ScoreStates = new List<List<Score>>();
List<Score> Scores = new List<Score>();

private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var lastState = ScoreStates.Last();
    ScoreStates.Remove(lastState);
    Scores = lastState;
}

public class Score
{
    public int TeamA { get; set; }
    public int TeamB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Okay using your idea i found how to do i will update my code so ppl can get the idea thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

What i meant is:

```
class List
{
    public int ListA { get; set; }
    public int ListB { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create 2 objects of class List one to operate on and the other to keep like a previous state (but it duplicate your objects!!!)

and the button will be:

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassListObj1.ListA = ClassListObj2.ListA;
        ClassListObj1.ListB = ClassListObj2.ListB;
    }
```

or even, but I'm not sure...

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassListObj1 = ClassListObj2;
    }
```

Remember, you'll have to do `ClassListObj2.ListA = ClassListObj1.ListA;` or `ClassListObj2.ListB = ClassListObj1.ListB;` before modifying the lists.

The idea with the struct is better, but it requires me to know more about your app, to elaborate.

Comment: How would i create these ClassListObj1 i got confused a bit. so what should i add before public int ListA{ get; set; }  ??
becuase i got the idea so i operate on one list while the other one has 1 step back, after that to undo i will just change the items from the List to be the items on the ObjList which is 1 step behind right?

Comment: `List ClassListObj1 = new List();` is an instance of your class List. Question: Isn't List a reserved word? You may need to change the name of the class ;)

Comment: yea i got your idea probably the name destroyed the execution :P 
but by reading your idea and the other answer i found how to do it thnx a lot :) i will post my updated code. @DIEGO CARRASCAL